# "la hay" vs. "la haya" vs. "la hubiera"

Tags: gramática

Quisiera preguntar por qué es “la hubiera” en vez de “la hay” o "la haya" en “[el valor razonable de la contraprestación recibida, si la hubiera, por la transacción, suceso o circunstancias que dieran lugar a la pérdida de control](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:149:0006:0021:ES:PDF)”. ¡Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En las oraciones condicionales, la prótasis (la parte encabezada con "si") puede usar tres tiempos verbales:

- presente de indicativo ("si la hay"), que indica que el suceso es razonablemente probable,
- pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo ("si la hubiera"), que indica que el suceso es improbable,
- o pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo ("si la hubiera habido"), que indica que el suceso es imposible (o más bien que es un hipotético suceso en el pasado que no ha ocurrido).

El presente de subjuntivo nunca se usa en la prótasis: <del>"si la haya"</del> es incorrecto. Mucha más información en la sección [§47.8](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OMNoKXsxoDWTzzZj) de la *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española*.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias otra vez por su ayuda, wimi!